How to get the client side url in layout.tsx in Next 14 app router
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default function Home() {
  const headersList = headers();
  
  headersList.get('host'); // to get domain
  headersList.get('next-url'); // to get url

  return <div>....</div>
}

Geeting guys.
I want to create a multi-tanent architecture saas application. Where I want to render a meta data based on the subdomain. For example:
subdomain.trendspot80.tech i want to grab this subdomain and pass to layout.tsx so that express backend select schema based on subdomain. By using headers().get('host') it gave me localhost:3000 ie host running on server. I am stuck in here.
using headers().get('referer') gave me null as it only provide domain if user redirect from client.
Here is code I have implemented in layout.tsx
import "@/global.css";
import Provider from "@/providers";
import type { Metadata } from "next";

import Footer from "@/components/molecules/Footer";
import MainHeader from "@/components/molecules/MainHeader";
import { getWebsiteLayouts } from "@/services/layout";
import { fonts } from "../../../public/assets/fonts";
import { getOrign } from "@/lib/storageServer";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const { data } = await getWebsiteLayouts('dallas_clothings.trendspot80.tech');
  if (!data) {
    return {
      title: "TrendSpot ",
      description: "Trendspot largest social media platform in the world",
    };
  }
  return {
    title: data?.results?.[0].name,
    description: data?.results?.[0].description || "",
  };
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  const origin = await getOrign();
  console.log(origin, 'o')
  const currentUrl = headers().get("x-saman");

  console.log("saman", currentUrl);
  const { data } = await getWebsiteLayouts(origin || '')

  const palette = {
    primary: data?.results?.[0].primaryColor || "#944e63",
    secondary: data?.results?.[0].secondaryColor || "#944e63"
  };

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={fonts.rubik.variable}>
      <body>
        <Provider palette={palette}>
          <MainHeader />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


I am expecting some one weather it is possible to get the subdomain in layout.tsx or not.

Create a Middleware to Capture Subdomain
First, create a middleware file (middleware.ts) in the root of your project. This middleware will extract the subdomain from the request and attach it to the request headers.
// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const host = url.hostname;

  // Assuming your main domain is 'trendspot80.tech'
  const mainDomain = 'trendspot80.tech';
  
  // Extract the subdomain
  const subdomain = host.endsWith(mainDomain)
    ? host.replace(`.${mainDomain}`, '')
    : null;

  // Attach subdomain to the request headers
  if (subdomain) {
    request.headers.set('x-subdomain', subdomain);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/:path*',
};

Access the Subdomain in Your Layout Component
Now, you can access the subdomain in your layout component by reading the custom header we set in the middleware.
import "@/global.css";
import Provider from "@/providers";
import type { Metadata } from "next";

import Footer from "@/components/molecules/Footer";
import MainHeader from "@/components/molecules/MainHeader";
import { getWebsiteLayouts } from "@/services/layout";
import { fonts } from "../../../public/assets/fonts";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  // Dummy domain to illustrate. Replace it with actual dynamic subdomain
  const subdomain = 'dallas_clothings';
  const { data } = await getWebsiteLayouts(`${subdomain}.trendspot80.tech`);
  
  if (!data) {
    return {
      title: "TrendSpot",
      description: "Trendspot largest social media platform in the world",
    };
  }

  return {
    title: data?.results?.[0]?.name,
    description: data?.results?.[0]?.description || "",
  };
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const headersList = headers();
  const subdomain = headersList.get('x-subdomain');

  console.log('Subdomain:', subdomain);

  const { data } = await getWebsiteLayouts(`${subdomain}.trendspot80.tech`);

  const palette = {
    primary: data?.results?.[0]?.primaryColor || "#944e63",
    secondary: data?.results?.[0]?.secondaryColor || "#944e63"
  };

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={fonts.rubik.variable}>
      <body>
        <Provider palette={palette}>
          <MainHeader />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
